# What's wrong with my grammar in Antlr 3?

Tags: antlr, grammar

```
grammar even_numbers;

NUMBER  :   '0'..'9';
EVEN_NUMBER  :  '2' | '4' | '6' | '8';

signedEvenNumber    : ('+' | '-' | ) NUMBER? EVEN_NUMBER;
```

The error is:

> error(208): :4:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: EVEN_NUMBER

[Please check the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuE8q.png)

Comment: What if you reorder `NUMBER` and `EVEN_NUMBER`? Otherwise the `NUMBER` is always matched.

Comment: @zerkms last number should be even aways to get an even number

Comment: Sure, it does not contradict with what I suggested, please read it again.

Comment: ANTLRWorks can be used to debug grammar files.

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite clear, if you read it carefully: the `EVEN_NUMBER` cannot be matched since `NUMBER` will match what `EVEN_NUMBER` also matches. And `NUMBER` is getting precedence because it is defined before `EVEN_NUMBER`.

What you can do is this:

```
signedEvenNumber : ('+' | '-' | ) number? EVEN_NUMBER;
number           : ZERO | ODD_NUMBER | EVEN_NUMBER;

ZERO        : '0';
ODD_NUMBER  : '1' | '3' | '5' | '7' | '9';
EVEN_NUMBER : '2' | '4' | '6' | '8';
```